# How to fix "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml)" in CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, installation, update

I've tried `yum update yum` and `yum clean all`, but neither help to resolve the following problem:

```
# yum install httpd --installroot=/opt/httpd2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
    * rpmforge: repoforge.spinellicreations.com
http://centos.karan.org/el%24releasever/extras/stable/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found 
Trying other mirror. 
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: 
    kbs-CentOS-Extras.
Please verify its path and try again
```

I've also tried deleting any `.repo` files for kbs-CentOS-Extras from `/etc/yum.repos.d`, and re-running the command, without any changes. Here's my system information, just in case:

```
# uname -a
Linux 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Sep 6 20:57:11 EDT 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am now using the `.repo` file [provided here](http://centos.karan.org/kbsingh-CentOS-Misc.repo). Here is my `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug
timeout=300
installonly_limit = 5

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h
```

The `yum.log` file is empty, but `/var/cache/yum/kbs-CentOS-Misc` contains a `repomd.xml` -- could this perhaps be used instead of the remote copy?

If not, any suggestions for how I can solve this?

Comment: Show us the relevant .repo file

Comment: Seems that `$releasever` is not correctly expanded (`el%24releasever`). Can you provide us your `/etc/yum.conf` file ?

Answer (score 1):

correct **el%24releasever** variable name to **$releasever** in your repo file. for more information about yum variables check [yum.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf).

> Variables
>
> There are a number of variables you can use to ease maintenance of
>   yum's configuration files. They are available in the values of several
>   options including name, baseurl and commands.
>
> ```
> $releasever This will be replaced with the value of the version of the package listed in distroverpkg. This defaults to the version of
> ```
>
> 'redhat-release' package.
>
> ```
> $arch This will be replaced with your architecture as listed by os.uname()[4] in Python.
>
> $basearch This will be replaced with your base architecture in yum. For example, if your $arch is i686 your $basearch will be i386.
>
> $uuid This will be replaced with a unique but persistent uuid for this machine. The value that is first generated will be stored in
> ```
>
> /var/lib/yum/uuid and reused until this file is deleted.
>
> ```
> $YUM0-$YUM9 These will be replaced with the value of the shell environment variable of the same name. If the shell environment
> ```
>
> variable does not exist then the configuration file variable will not
>   be replaced.  As of 3.2.28, any file in /etc/yum/vars is turned into a
>   variable named after the filename (or overrides any of the above
>   variables).
>
> Note that no warnings/errors are given if the files are unreadable, so
>   creating files that only root can read may be confusing for users.
>
> Also note that only the first line will be read and all new line
>   characters are removed, as a convenience. However, no other checking
>   is performed on the data. This means it is possible to have bad
>   character data in any value.

also [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0) will be useful for understanding yum variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue by adding the [CentALT x86_64](http://pkgs.org/centos-5/centalt-x86_64/) repository. I first downloaded [centalt-release-5-3.noarch.rpm](http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/5/x86_64/centalt-release-5-3.noarch.rpm), then ran:

```
rpm -Uvh centalt-release*rpm
```

After this, running my original command resulted in package conflicts (it was unhappy that I was re-installing a different version of `httpd-tools`, even if to an alternate installation directory.)

Since I was only installing to `/opt/httpd2` for testing purposes, I abandoned that idea, and successfully installed by running `yum upgrade httpd`.